# Distributed Gradle Daemons

Tags: android, gradle, build

I am trying to make my builds faster by distributing Gradle tasks (like gradle test --tests subproject1 on VM1 and gradle test --tests subproject2 on VM2) across VMs.

I want the daemon to be persisted for the performance benefit.

I was thinking of starting Daemons in the foreground, so the container doesn’t quit after it is done.

1. Is there an API for working with the Gradle Daemon? Maybe something like the Gradle Tooling API
2. I can’t be the first to have done this. Is there some other project that
   I can look at for reference as I build this?